# Manually update build number in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps, for some reason it has lost the build number and started with zero again.

I want to update the build number, so it will continue from my last build number (25).

In team city, it is easy to update build number, here in azure I could not find where it is stored.

Comment: I dont think its possible with yaml builds, might be possible with regular builds

Comment: What's the result after you trying with counter?

Comment: I have manually setup build. And can't find how to insert counter variable. The GUI for variables seems to treat anything like a literal string

Comment: I include screenshots for UI designer.

Comment: Make sure there isn't whitespace at the end of variable ($[ counter('counter',25)])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these screenshots for UI designer (**Make sure there isn't whitespace at the end of variable value**):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are my saviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable with `counter`:

```
variables:
  version: $[ counter('counter',25) ]
```

In the build number use this variable:

```
name: $(version)
```

The above it's for yaml builds, in the classic editor is the same, define the variable in the variables tab and in the options tab put the variable in the build number format field.

More info about the `counter` you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions).

Comment: This works. The sad thing is, it does not update the build's display name (in dev.azure.com when I start a new build). It always displays "$(version)" as the name of the build. How did you manage to force update the build name once $(version) got a value?

Comment: @thomasgalliker you can with `##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(version)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#build-commands

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I got it working using format command:

name: $[format('{0}', variables['releaseVersion'])]